# Why is id_dict out of scope when converting map to np.array?

Tags: python, lambda, scope

I am trying to reindex some dictionary using **lambda** function.

I am trying to get the unique index from "data" and re-index them in "id_dict". However, when i try to use the mapping and convert it to a np.array, it seems to be out of scope.

```py
uniq = list(set(data))
id_dict = {old: new+1 for new, old in enumerate(sorted(uniq))}
seq = map(lambda x: id_dict[x], data)
mapped_data = np.fromiter(seq, dtype=np.int32)
```

```
        2
        3 id_dict = {old: new+1 for new, old in enumerate(sorted(uniq))}
  ----> 4 seq = map(lambda x: id_dict[x], data)
        5 mapped_data = np.fromiter(seq, dtype=np.int32)

 NameError: name 'id_dict' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you please include a more detailed example, so one can replicate it to see what's happening? What's in variable "data"?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this error when I copy your code. Have you checked you didn't make any error? If not, can you provide more informations about the context?

Comment: code is working fine, if you using ipython/ jupter i think you need to execute the line 2

Comment: data = [1,2,3,5,6]


For me its crashing. I am using python3

Comment: @paulagomezduran this is output `array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` for your data, on the code, cannt reproduce this error

Comment: @paulagomezduran It's working fine for me too. `array([0, 1, 2, 3])` and **id_dict** returns `{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}`.

Comment: Sorry, I am not having the error when I try outside the project. Must be something else crushing... Thank you!